# Continuously Updating Label in ListView Template

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've got a list of objects that I'm binding to a ListView and using a DataTemplate to show in a Xamarin app. So far, pretty simple. But the kicker is that I want one of the controls (a label specifically) to update continually.

So far this is what I have...

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemsListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          HasUnevenRows="true"
          RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
          IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
          ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Padding="10">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                           LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                           Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"
                           FontSize="16" />
                    <mycountdown:TimerLabel Text="{Binding TimeRemainingString}"
                                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                                            FontSize="13" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And the code behind for my TimerLabel class...

```
public class TimerLabel : Label
{
    private bool beating;
    public TimerLabel()
    {
        StartHeartbeat();
    }

    public void StartHeartbeat()
    {
        //only start beating again if not currently beating.
        if (!beating)
        {
            beating = true;
            Heartbeat();
        }
    }

    public void StopHeartbeat()
    {
        beating = false;
    }

    async void Heartbeat()
    {
        while (beating)
        {
            this.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString();
        }
    }
}
```

This **works**, but the problem is that the heartbeat for each item in the list keeps running even when I navigate away from the page.

Ideally, the heartbeat would only run for items that are visible on screen, but I would settle for letting them all run and just disabling them when I leave the page.

The problem is I can't figure out how to access the StopHeartbeat() method from the page's code behind or the view model.

It's not going to be limited to only Labels either. I will end up having a few other controls that need to update in the UI thread continuously, but this is the simplest one to start with.

If there's another way I should be doing this, please say so.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396160/xamarin-contentview-view-lifecycle

Comment: `PageDisappearing` can be used when leave page. `INotifyPropertyChanged` can be used when model changed.

Comment: are you trying to access it from your viewmodel?

Comment: Jason's comment worked perfectly. I was trying to figure out how to link to those events anyways since I used them in another part of my program, but I just couldn't figure out how to do it inside user controls.

Answer (score 0):

if you are Bind **List** in ListItem Source then please change it from **List** to **ObservableCollection** it will work let me know if any question or can you upload viewModel code as well

Answer (score 0):

Answered by the top comment in my post.